# Does Sonic & Knuckles provide the "lock-on" tech on current gen consoles?

Tags: virtual-console, xbox-live-arcade, sonic-and-knuckles

As some no doubt remember, Sonic & Knuckles provided back when it was released "lock on technology" which allowed it to connect to Sonic 2 and Sonic 3. Is this accounted for in the current generation consoles emulators, the Xbox 360 Arcade and Wii Virtual Console?

Comment: Waited 9 hours before I went and did some more digging and found my answer. Hopefully it's all right that I waited awhile before answering my own question.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. One can read up more [in this Meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question), but to summarize - waiting some time or immediately answering it are both acceptable practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did a little more digging and found the info needed. On the XBLA site for [Sonic & Knuckles](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/s/sonicknucklesxbla/) it says it does. Additionally found on [GoNintendo.com](http://gonintendo.com/viewstory.php?id=114384), it says the Wii VC version keeps the lock on tech as well.

Comment: Actually, in the original Mega Drive/Genesis, you could put another non-Sonic game on top of Sonic & Knuckles and it would allow you to play ONE special stage for that cartridge. On the other hand, putting Sonic 1 would allow you to play countless special stages. It won't be the actual "lock-on" feature unless it allows locking on any cartridge. (but, still, allowing just Sonic 1 is good enough)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lock on feature is present. Gametrailers mentions it specifcally in their review [here](http://www.gametrailers.com/video/review-pod-sonic-4/706286).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lock-on feature is completely present, allowing you to play Sonic 2 and Sonic 3 with knuckles, and includes the easteregg, which can be accessed trough a "fake" lock-on with the original Sonic the Hedgehog game leading you to the No Way? No Way! screen.